# Change "TAX/VAT number" title on account creation page?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, vat

I want to remove the VAT portion of the title when creating a new account.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can see inside of

```
magento_path/app/design/frontend/base/default/customer/form/regiter.phtml
```

This part of code:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat')
```

If you search for this block you arrive to this path:

```
magento_path/app/design/frontend/base/default/customer/widget/taxvat.phtml
```

Inside this file you can see this:

```
echo $this->__('Tax/VAT number')
```

You can change with some conditions on registration page.

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select the answer as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a custom theme. You should ask the provider where is the phtml you need to modify and/or turn on template path hints to see it by yourself.
To turn on Template hints go to System -> Configuration -> Developer and select on the top left the website or store you are using. After that you will see a select called Template Path Hints. Turn it on. Guide with images [here.](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/)
After that you will be able to remove/modify the TAX/VAT field in the correct phtml.

Comment: They don't exist anymore lol .  I'll try the hints. Thought maybe they were in the CSV files for each language but after modifying anything with"VAT" in it it still does  nothing which leads me to believe there is a phtml file somewhere

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is option in admin panel weather you want to show the vat/Tax on register page or not you can check there Go to System->Customer->customer configuration->Name and address option->Show Tax/VAT Number you can edit the entry over there.

Regards,
Bhavesh Gadoya.